# authentication and authorization design in RESTful web application

Tags: jax-rs, restful-authentication, restful-architecture, web-application-design

I have an web application built using RESTful services (JAX-RS).
There are REST calls, and simple JSPs with js files to handle data.

Now I want to implement authentication and authorization in service. What I did earlier was to implement simple filter and inside each service check for @HttpRequestContext for if session has user object. Since it I want to expose service to say, external webapp, I will have to hard code system as there is no standard.

I feel this is not good design. Is there a design pattern to solve this common issue ?

Comment: means you want to create a service like SSO, where authentication and authorization project deployed somewhere else and through that you get service ?

Comment: Not exactly SSO. I want to have some AAA implementation such that I dont have to pollute my web services with all isAuthorized code. Secondly, Say my services are used within current webapp (It has both services as well as jsps (consumers))  and say, mobile app.  Some standard AAA mechanism suffice both.

Comment: If your system is large enough you can probably look into OAuth protocol. It entirely isolates the authentication and authorization from the rest of the app.

Comment: You can try out http://shiro.apache.org/ too.

Comment: And https://www.stormpath.com/ too :-) There are a lot of complete solutions I think...